# Particles system, a delay in an array

Tags: java

I am learning java at the moment and trying to make different features and systems. Right now I am trying to make a really simple particle system, but I have problem.

```
public void eDelay()
{
    try 
    {
        Thread.sleep(17);
     } catch (InterruptedException e) 
     {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
public void engine()
{   
    int i = 0;
    while (i < particles.size())
    {

        Particle a = (Particle) particles.get(i);
        eDelay();
            a.move();
            i = i + 1;
    }
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    engine();
    repaint();
}
```

This is a part of my code where the particles suppose to move. It works fine and they do move, but **I want them to move one after another one with a delay(17)**. However, they move all at once and not one after another.
(particles) is an arrayList with 50 elements in it, each element containst a position for a particle.
(a.move()) is just a movement method where particle moves up.

Don't worry for the rest of the code, the problem is in this part.

Graphics, positioning of the particles, movement of the particles, and other things work fine.

Comment: `"Don't worry for the rest of the code, the problem is in this part. - Graphics, positioning of the particles, movement of the particles, and other things work fine."` -- How can you say this when you know what the cause of your problem is? You could be creating a Swing application (which is part of the rest of the code) and calling `Thread.sleep(...)` on the event thread. So make no assumptions, tell us all of the story, show more pertinent code, and let's help you solve this. If this is Swing then that's your problem -- don't call `Thread.sleep`, use a Swing Timer!~

Comment: I am a bit confused about that, I am using a swing timer as a game timer, so the program in a continuous loop. Wouldn't the two timers interact with each other in a strange way?

Comment: @user2522083: The two Timers should run just fine, but whether the code controlled by them will interact will depend on how you've written your program. I don't think that it's possible for us to say. The Swing code should behave OK since it is all single threaded.

Answer (score 1):

Going to make my comment an answer:

> "Don't worry for the rest of the code, the problem is in this part. - Graphics, positioning of the particles, movement of the particles, and other things work fine."`

How can you say this when you know what the cause of your problem is? You could be creating a Swing application (which is part of the rest of the code) and calling `Thread.sleep(...)` on the event thread. So make no assumptions, tell us all of the story, show more pertinent code, and let's help you solve this.

Edit: I now see that this is in fact a Swing application and so that's likely your problem, although you don't show us where the Thread.sleep is called.Calling `Thread.sleep(...)` puts the thread that calls it asleep, and if this is the Swing event thread (or EDT), it will put your entire application to sleep -- not a good thing to do.  So don't call `Thread.sleep` on the event thread and use a Swing Timer instead. The tutorials will show you how.

And of course again, don't make any assumptions.

Comment: This is my full code. It contains only 3 classes. hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/882 I am completely out of ideas. It appears to me that I had a wrong understanding of how arrays work.

Comment: Ok, I have the answer, will post in a six hours or so(not allowed yet).

Answer (score 1):

You should call repaint in the `engine()` loop instead of `actionPerformed()`.

Comment: good catch, 1+. Of course that would be done in a Swing Timer, not in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, this is actually a bit weird but I just rewrote the engine class again into a for loop and it works.

```
public void engine()
{
    goingcrazy = goingcrazy + gameTimer.getDelay();
    for(int i = 0; i < particles.size(); i++)
    {
        if (goingcrazy > 1000*i)
        {
        Particle a = (Particle) particles.get(i);
        a.move();
        }

    }
}
```

I already posted a link for the full code so if you are interested you just need to change the old engine class with the one I just posted.